# Can't access Kubernetes dashboard via ingress

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress, oracle-cloud-infrastructure

So I installed the kubernetes dashboard with the following manifests:

> kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/dashboard/v2.7.0/aio/deploy/recommended.yaml

Then I created this ingress resource pointing to my dashboard service

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: kubernetes-dashboard-nginx-ingress
  namespace: kubernetes-dashboard
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/backend-protocol: "HTTPS"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-passthrough: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/force-ssl-redirect: "true"
    nginx.org/upstream-zone-size: "0"
spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx
  rules:
  - host: k8s-dashboard.<myDomain>
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: kubernetes-dashboard
            port:
              number: 443
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - k8s-dashboard.<myDomain>
    # secretName omitted to use default wildcard certificate
```

Then if I do a curl from my Raspberry (or any other device) to the URL I get an error

```
guille@raspberrypi:~/K8S/kubernetes-dashboard $ curl https://k8s-dashboard.<myDomain>/
Client sent an HTTP request to an HTTPS server.
```

But if I curl from inside the cluster (with a curl pod)

```
guille@raspberrypi:~/K8S/kubernetes-dashboard $ kubectl get svc -n kubernetes-dashboard
NAME                        TYPE        CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)    AGE
dashboard-metrics-scraper   ClusterIP   10.96.68.254    <none>        8000/TCP   78m
kubernetes-dashboard        ClusterIP   10.96.169.120   <none>        443/TCP    78m
guille@raspberrypi:~/K8S/kubernetes-dashboard $ kubectl exec mycurlpod -n default -i --tty -- curl -k https://10.96.169.120
<!--
Copyright 2017 The Kubernetes Authors.

Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
You may obtain a copy of the License at

    http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
limitations under the License.
--><!DOCTYPE html><html lang="en" dir="ltr"><head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Kubernetes Dashboard</title>
  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="assets/images/kubernetes-logo.png">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
<style>html,body{height:100%;margin:0}*::-webkit-scrollbar{background:transparent;height:8px;width:8px}</style><link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.243e6d874431c8e8.css" media="print" onload="this.media='all'"><noscript><link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.243e6d874431c8e8.css"></noscript></head>

<body>
  <kd-root></kd-root>
<script src="runtime.134ad7745384bed8.js" type="module"></script><script src="polyfills.5c84b93f78682d4f.js" type="module"></script><script src="scripts.2c4f58d7c579cacb.js" defer></script><script src="en.main.3550e3edca7d0ed8.js" type="module"></script>


</body></html>
```

As you can see, the dashboard is correctly deployed, but I can't reach it via ingress.

Any idea on this?

Answer (score 1):

There is an example of ingress configuration that works fine for me:

```yaml
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: dashboard-local
  namespace: kube-system
  annotations:
    # restrict to private network scopes
    "nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/whitelist-source-range": "10.1.1.0/24"
    "nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/force-ssl-redirect": "true"
    "nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-passthrough": "true"
    "nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/backend-protocol": "HTTPS"
spec:
  # ingressClassName: public - optional if you need to specify ingress class
  rules:
  - host: dashboard.local
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: kubernetes-dashboard
            port:
              number: 443
```

Make sure there is a valid subnet specified in `whitelist-source-range` parameter and namespace of `kubernetes-dashboard` service is specified correctly in a line #5.

Also double check if there is no any other ingress created for kubernetes dashboard via command `kubectl get ingress -A` to avoid collision.

Answer (score 0):

For SSL Passthrough to work, you need to have the flag `--enable-ssl-passthrough` enabled for the ingress-nginx pod. That could explain the issue here. So, for the `args:` section of the container in the manifest you deploy, add `--enable-ssl-passthrough` to the list, then try again.

Also, please take a look at the ingress-nginx pod logs; they might tell you already what the issue is. As a sidenote: You can also test the connection inside the cluster going through the ingress-nginx by curl'ing the ingress-nginx and setting the host header to the service you want to reach.

See also: https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/tls/#ssl-passthrough

Comment: As was mentioned by author, he wants to have an access from another device, so need to provide an access from other networks via `whitelist-source-range`